# Compass sprite - avoid using extends when including a sprite

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am using Compass to generate my sprites, and it is working beautifully, but I have run into one small annoyance. I am not able to include an individual sprite using the @include statement when inside of another @include, such as a media query mixin, which I commonly use. My sprite SCSS looks like this:

```
.sp {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

$sp-sprite-dimensions: true;
$sp-sprite-base-class: '.sp';
$sprite-layout: smart;
@import "sp/*.png";
@include all-sp-sprites;
```

In another location, I am attempting to do this:

```
.logo {
    a {
        @include break($break1) {
            @include sp-sprite(logo-small);
        }
    }
}
```

Nested @include statements are fine by SCSS, but it doesn't allow for @extend statements within @include statements, and apparently the sprite @include is generating an @extend statement behind the scenes, which I do not want. Anybody know a way around this?

EDIT:

It's been brought to my attention by @lolmaus that the real problem is that I am nesting an @extend inside of a media query. I guess that's not allowed, any way around it?

Comment: You seem to be doing some strange thing. Is `sp-sprite` a mixin coded by you? Please provide full code.

Comment: @lolmaus No, it's a mixin that is auto generated by compass. See "Selector Control" here: [http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/)

Comment: The matter is that it is possible to use the foo-sprite mixin inside another mixin. [This[(https://gist.github.com/lolmaus/2101b2938c665a3d44de) compiles fine. That's why i thought that you had overridden the mixin. Please provide full code and error text, so that we could match reported erroneous line with code. Use http://gist.github.com to share multiple large files at once.

Comment: Oh, i got it. The problem is not that your extend is inside a mixin. The problem is that it's inside a media query!

Comment: Oh, I see, I guess that is the problem, thanks for tracking it down. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Compass sprites inside media queries is not possible, at least the way it's described in the documentation.

There are a couple of workarounds:

- [creating sprites manually](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/617#issuecomment-2746951) via command line;
- using a [custom mixin](https://gist.github.com/dfadler/3105369).

Comment: how do you use the custom mixin, I tried it, It gets included. But I am probably doing something wrong

Comment: 1) Put the mixin in a partial, e. g. `_get-sprite.scss`. 2) Import the partial somewhere in the beginning of your code. 3) Apply the mixin like this: `.element { @include get-sprite(...); }`. Make sure you provide all arguments correctly. 4) Compile. If the result is unsatisfactory, please share: a) your SASS code; b) the resulting CSS code; c) explainations what you want to achieve and in what is the result different from your expectation.

Comment: Oh come on, just study it, it's so short! PS Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SASS (SCSS) mixin for generating a sprite declaration block that will work with media queries

**SCSS:**

```
// http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/
@mixin get-sprite($map, $sprite, $repeat: no-repeat, $height: true, $width: true) {

  //http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-file
  $sprite-image: sprite-file($map, $sprite);

  // http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-url
  $sprite-map: sprite-url($map);

  // http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-position
  $sprite-position: sprite-position($map, $sprite);

  // Returns background
  background: $sprite-map $sprite-position $repeat;

  // http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/image-dimensions/
  // Checks to see if the user wants height returned
  @if $height == true {
    // Gets the height of the sprite-image
    $sprite-height: image-height($sprite-image);
    // Returns the height
    height: $sprite-height; }

  // http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/image-dimensions/
  // Checks to see if the user wants height returned
  @if $width == true {
    // Gets the width of the sprite-image
    $sprite-width: image-width($sprite-image);
    // Returns the width
    width: $sprite-width; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$icons: sprite-map("sprites/icons/*.png"); // define a sprite map 

// ... later

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .video .overlay {
        @include get-sprite($icons, play-btn-large);
    }
}
```

[Source: GitHubGist - brubrant / get-sprite.scss](https://gist.github.com/brubrant/3166895)

Comment: the only reason this works is because you've brought the media query outside of a mixin. I'm looking for a way to leave it inside.

Answer (score 0):

The following code describes how to do it

Gist: [@extend Compass sprites in @media queries](https://gist.github.com/shaharhesse/dc7c75979dfc1dd11e55)

```
/*
 * A simple way to extend Compass sprite classes within media queries.
 * Based on the knowledge gained here: http://www.sitepoint.com/cross-media-query-extend-sass/
 * I admit it's nowhere near as clever, but it does work :)
 */


/*
 * Set-up sprites for each media size
 */

// default
@import "icons-sm/*.png"
@include all-icons-sm-sprites

// corresponding sprites for larger devices
// notice that @import is within the @media query
// that's critical!

@media (min-width: $large)
  @import "icons-lg/*.png"
  @include all-icons-lg-sprites

/*
 * Now you can do something like this
 */

// an example mixin

@mixin social-links($size)
  $socials: facebook, twitter, youtube
  @each $social in $socials
    &.#{$social}
      @extend .icons-#{$size}-#{$social}

/*
 * Put to use
 */

// assuming you've got mark-up like this

<p class="social">
  <a href="#" class="facebook">facebook</a>
  <a href="#" class="twitter">twitter</a>
  <a href="#" class="youtube">youtube</a>
</p>

// you can do this                          
.social
  a
    @include social-links(sm)
    width: 25px
    height: 25px
    @media (min-width: $large)
      @include social-links(lg)
      width: 50px
      height: 50px
```